# How to implement this cell animation with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm trying to make [this animation](http://youtu.be/ZbXSOX2kHys)

For the list, I think I can use `UICollectionView`, but the animation part seem to be tricky.

Any idea on this?

Comment: For animation of UICollectionViewCell, animate layer of cell when decelarating of UICollectionView in the delegate method..

Comment: Whenever user starts scrolling, move the layers of visible cells to specific '-y' poisition and animate and restore the y position when the collection view decelerate method.. let me know if this makes sense..

Comment: https://github.com/TeehanLax/UICollectionView-Spring-Demo

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the springing animation part, that is not very tricky - Apple has a demo of exactly that behavior in same code for `UIDynamics` (iOS7+ only).

There is another example here that looks very close to what you are after:

http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html

Look in the middle for an animated example.  It even uses collection views.

Comment: That's very close to what i need, but i want my app to support iOS6.

Comment: That would be completed solution (UICollectionView + iOS6 Dynamic) if i could find a clone of UIDynamic for iOS6. It would probably be a wrapper of Box2d. i will look further.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kendall said, you really need to try `UIDynamics`.

For a quick workaround, I just tried below code. It works somewhat good and related to your code.
I don't know about performance. So It may create a performance lack in your project.

**It is just an idea. If it is not working for you, leave it as it is.**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -50);
    }];
    [self delayBy:0.5 code:^{ // call block of code after time interval
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: use this code in CollectionView-simple sample code from Apple ( use this instead of your block style code: [self performSelector:@selector(restore:) withObject:cell afterDelay:0.5];) it doesn't work in iOS 6. In iOS 7, it animates only new cells inserted in the collection view.

Comment: Because of we have this code inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method it won't get called for the visible cells in the screen. For that you need to create the cells without reusing or otherwise you need to handle the animation for visible cells in `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method of `UIScrollView` (`UICollectionView` is subclass of `UIScrollView`). Hope you get what I said.